# Module tesnorflow has no attribute "UninitializedVariable" tensorflow hub error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I have tensorflow version "1.14.0" and pip3 is also updated. But when I do:-

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops' has no attribute 'UninitializedVariable'
```

Tensorflow hub has version 0.5.0. Some answers on stack overflow have suggested that tensorflow version should be greater than 1.7.0 and mine is greater and still I don't know why is hub not being imported. The complete traceback of error is:-

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-d70b4e927300> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      2 import tensorflow as tf
----> 3 import tensorflow_hub as hub

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py in <module>
     27 # error message is thrown instead of an obscure error of missing
     28 # symbols at executing the imports.
---> 29 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
     30 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import register_module_for_export
     31 from tensorflow_hub.feature_column import image_embedding_column

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/estimator.py in <module>
     23 from absl import logging
     24 import tensorflow as tf
---> 25 from tensorflow_hub import tf_utils
     26 from tensorflow_hub import tf_v1
     27 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/tf_utils.py in <module>
     31 # depending on TensorFlow internal implementation details.
     32 # pylint: disable=g-direct-tensorflow-import
---> 33 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_v2
     34 # pylint: enable=g-direct-tensorflow-import
     35 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py in <module>
    164 from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
    165 from tensorflow.python.training import checkpoint_utils
--> 166 from tensorflow.python.training.tracking import tracking
    167 from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation
    168 from tensorflow.python.util import nest

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/tracking.py in <module>
     21 import weakref
     22 
---> 23 from tensorflow.python.eager import def_function
     24 from tensorflow.python.eager import function as defun
     25 from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in <module>
     38 
     39 
---> 40 class UnliftedInitializerVariable(resource_variable_ops.UninitializedVariable):
     41   """Variable which does not lift its initializer out of function context.
     42 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops' has no attribute 'UninitializedVariable'
```

I have tried uninstalling tf completely and then installing again, reinstalling tf hub and updating pip so far. Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, can't repro witt tensorflow==1.14.0 and tensorflow_hub==0.5.0. Maybe you could file a bug at http://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/ with a self-contained reproduction for the problem, starting from pip installs in an empty virtualenv.

Comment: In your system tf==1.14.0 and tf_hub==0.5.0 work fine?

Comment: Yes, tf==1.14.0 and tf_hub==0.5.0 work for me (Linux, also Python 3.6); certainly as far as the two import statements at the top of the stracktrace in your question.